# Leaflet: misalignment of tiles and negative y coordinates

Tags: javascript, leaflet, tile

I am trying to generate a custom non-geographical map with Leaflet using my own tiles.

For the moment I created 10x10 dummy tiles of size 256x256px each with a random solid color using *imagemagick*.
They are placed in public/map-tiles/1/map_x_y.png where x takes values from 0 to 9 (resp. y).

Since this is a non-geographical map, I paid attention to change crs to L.CRS.Simple (see http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html):

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  minZoom: 1,
  maxZoom: 1,
  center: [0, 0],
  crs: L.CRS.Simple
}).setView([0, 0], 1);

L.tileLayer('/map-tiles/{z}/map_{x}_{y}.png', {
    bounds: [[0, 0], [2560, 2560]],
    tms: true
}).addTo(map);
```

However this produces tiles slightly shifted and thus misaligned:

[image: misaligned tiles]

Also, tiles with negative y coordinates are fetched, which results in 404d requests, as seen in the console.

What can be the cause of this behavior?

EDIT 1: as IvanSanchez pointed out, the misalignment was caused by the missing  leaflet.css stylesheet.

I still have the problem with negative coordinates. As suggested, I added bounds (see updated code above). Observations:

- with bounds [[0, 0], [2560, 2560]]: no tiles displayed altogether, blank screen.
- with bounds [[-1280, -1280], [1280, 1280]]: all tiles displayed, but negative tiles fetched (eg (5,-1)) resulting in 404s.

EDIT 2: after several tests it looks like the negative tiles are indeed the product of the y-axis handling (http://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html). The origin is top left, y going downward. I expected the tiles below the origin to be fetched, not above.

What I tried in order to keep my convention with x and y both increasing (that is x increases to the right, y increases downward, tiles with positive coordinate components are fetched from 0 to 9):

- setting `tms: true` for tileLayer. No success, tiles with negative y are still fetched .
- changing `{y}` to `{-y}` in the tileLayer source path. Results in `Error: No value provided for variable {-y}`. My script is using Leaflet 1.3.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a map with `L.CRS.Simple`, all `TileLayer`s have infinite bounds by default.

If you want a `TileLayer` to request tiles only in a given area, read the [Leaflet API documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#tilelayer), specifically a `TileLayer` option named `bounds` (inherited from `GridLayer` options). Let me quote:

> `bounds`
>   type `LatLngBounds`
>   default `undefined`
>   If set, tiles will only be loaded inside the set `LatLngBounds`.

You also mention:

> Weirdly enough, it tries to fetch tiles with negative coordinates [...]

That's not weird, it's behaviour as designed. There is nothing inherently wrong (nor weird) with negative coordinates, and negative tile coordinates are valid and [documented in some tile standards](https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification#TileMap_Diagram)

---

So if you have 10x10 tiles of 256px in size ranging from [0, 0] to [10, 10], you might want something like

```
L.tileLayer('/map-tiles/map_{x}_{y}.png', {
  bounds: [[0, 0], [2560, 2560]]
}).addTo(map);
```

If the center of your data is the [0, 0] point and your tiles span from [-5, -5] to [5, 5] you might instead want something like

```
L.tileLayer('/map-tiles/map_{x}_{y}.png', {
  bounds: [[-1280, -1280], [1280, 1280]]
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, and sorry for the poorly chosen wording... I meant to say I was intrigued more than anything else. I get the concept of bouding, but bounds: [[0, 0], [2560, 2560]] removes the tiles altogether (blank area) and [[-1280, -1280], [1280, 1280]] produces that same misalignment of the tiles. Could there be something wrong with my map.setView([0, 0], 1)?

Comment: Oh, wait, the misalignment can actually be a lack of `leaflet.css` in your webpage.

Comment: Can you update your question with this information, maybe a link to see how it fails? e.g. like https://plnkr.co/edit/WxoYaRwbiDAZ37oEwXlQ?p=preview . And if the problem is the negative `y` coordinate (please, be specific when explaining your problem!!), read up http://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html until the very end.

Comment: I updated the question. I will try and put a link as soon as I get home.

Answer (score -1):

The problem boils down to  two aspects:

- **misalignment**: the leaflet.css stylesheet was missing and simply needed to be linked to in the HTML of the page.
- **negative tiles fetched**: for Leaflet the y-axis goes downward. I expected tiles to be fetched from left to right, top to bottom with an origin set to the top left corner. Instead, negative y's were fetched. Since my tiles' names are *map_x_y.png* where x and y take values in {0:9}, this resulted in 404d requests. Setting negative bounds fixed the issue with `bounds: [[0,0],[-1230,1230]]` (notice the minus sign). 1230 corresponds to the number of tiles at zoom 0 times the size in pixel of one tile.